# Create in Angular a form in Angular on complex JSON

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on an Angular web application. In a component, I receive a complex JSON that I need to create a reactive form that respect the JSON structure. Just to show an example of my JSON:

```
{
    "annoAl": 2019,
    "annoDal": 2019,
    "azienda": {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": null,
        "codice": "201",        
        "regioneId": 1,
        "sigla": "dummy"
    },
    "comune": null,
    "descrizione": "Turno ripartito",
    "giorni": [{
        "chiuso": false,
        "orari": [{
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        },
        {
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        }]
    },
    {
        "chiuso": false,
        "orari": [{
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        },
        {
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        }]
    },
    {
        "chiuso": false,
        "orari": [{
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        },
        {
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        }]
    }],
    "invertiIntervallo": false,
    "meseGiornoAl": null,
    "meseGiornoDal": null,
    "provenienza": "AZIENDA",
    "regione": null,
    "ripartizione": {
        "durataTurno": 7,
        "gruppi": [{
            "gruppo": 0,
            "sede": {
                "id": 11,
                "uuid": "11",
                "idFarmacia": 13,
                "idComune": 163,                
            }
        },
        {
            "gruppo": 1,
            "sede": {
                "id": 12,
                "uuid": "12",
                "idFarmacia": 11,
                "idComune": 163,                
            }
        },
        {
            "gruppo": 2,
            "sede": {
                "id": 8,
                "uuid": "8",
                "idFarmacia": 8,
                "idComune": 164,                
            }
        }],
        "gruppiNumero": 4
    },
    "ripetiAnnualmente": false,
    "sede": null,
    "tipo": "TURNO_RIPARTITO",
    "uuid": null
}
```

To accomplish this task, I build manually the reactive form (the fields are known). Is there a simple method to do this? I try using `FormBuilder` but it has some problem with arrays.

```js
formBuilder.group(jsonObject)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the stackblitz with current progress?

Comment: Maybe this package can help you: https://github.com/ngx-formly

Comment: There is not anything out of the box that can generate a form from a complex json. You can write a function that goes through the json an create formcontrols/formarrays/forgroups based on your json. Also check dynamic forms: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: Can also look into ngx-sub-form https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-dynamic-forms